# How to stream my webcam through my site?

Tags: python, webcam

Is it possible to stream my webcam form my local machine that's connected to the internet to show up on my website without using any media server or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with some kind of java applet or flash/silverlight application, just look at sites like "chat roulette"

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting for other people to see it, then no.

Web pages have two scopes: Client and Server. Something running on one Client (user) cannot be shown to other Clients (users) without it being on the Server.

You can use things like [UStream](http://www.ustream.tv/), but I would expect that they are using a media server or something similar on the back end to show the stream to other clients (users).

Comment: Okay so If going to stream to the server instead, do you know any opensource solution for some kind of a media server?

Comment: I have not used any, but a google search on open source media server showed a ton of results. One that might be helpful is http://webcamspy.sourceforge.net/